# Index of each CharAt and multiplying each index number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to multiply each every index number together and seems like parseInt also return a decimal in the end...Not sure why?

```
    var decNum = "12312312312312";

    if( decNum.length == 14)
    {
        var lastnum = decNum.charAt(13);


        var newNum = parseInt(decNum)/14; // rather 1231231231231 it shows 1231231231231.2 should be 13 nums left without last digit in int.


        var validNum = [1,7,4,2,8,7,3,2,1,2,3,4,1,3];
        var sum;

        for (var i = 0; i < validNum.length; i++) {

        //since I can't use charAt for for INT so parse to string and parse it back to int to do the math.
            sum += parseInt(validNum[i]) * parseInt(String(newNum.charAt(i)));
        }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here but note that arrays are zero based and if tbe length is 14 then the legal elements are in positions 0 to 13.

Comment: what result do you expect? btw, you need not to parse a number and you have a dot in the result of a division (if tat works with an empty string), that leads to a `NaN`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: `lastnum` is an empty string (length !== index), `newNum` will be a floating point number (just do the math to see why), `sum` is undefined hence it will be `NaN` after the loop (if it would work), `newNum` is a number and has no `.charAt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

parseInt returns a number, so `var newNum = parseInt(decNum)/14;` results in `newNum` being a *number*, not a string. So, you can't use `charAt` on a number - you want the string. You have decimals because when you divide an integer (`decNum`) by 14, the result is a continuing decimal.

If you want to use explicit type conversions:

`const newNum = String(parseInt(decNum / 14));`

You don't need to `parseInt` the elements of `validNum` since they're already integers.

Your `sum` is not initialized to 0, so subsequent `sum +=` lines will fail.

Even after fixing that, it would still be more elegant to use array methods to iterate over the string, though:

```js
const decNum = "12312312312312";
if( decNum.length == 14) {
  const newNum = String(parseInt(decNum / 14));
  const validNum = [1,7,4,2,8,7,3,2,1,2,3,4,1,3];
  const charCodeArr = newNum.split('').map(char => char.charAt(0));
  const sum = charCodeArr.reduce((sumSoFar, charCode, i) => {
    return sumSoFar + (charCode * validNum[i]);
  }, 0);
  console.log(sum);
}
```

Comment: _"so subsequent sum += lines will fail"_ - that totally depends on the definition of _fail_. There won't be any error thrown, but the result won't be a number. `parseInt()` is not meant to be a `Math.floor()` replacement. `charCode` is not the numerical representation of a character but the character itself hence the `reduce` only works because of implicit type conversion.

Comment: I think something a variable named `sum` which is intended to be a number but actually resolves to NaN would certainly qualify as "failing".

Answer (score 0):

everything works fine now, thanks, everyone.

```
    var decNum = "12312312312312";

    if( decNum.length == 14)
    {
        var lastnum = decNum.charAt(13);


        var newNum = String(parseInt(decNum)/14);

        var validNum = [1,7,4,2,8,7,3,2,1,2,3,4,1,3];
        var sum = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < validNum.length; i++) {
            sum += parseInt(validNum[i]) * parseInt(newNum.charAt(i));
        }
```